# Is it necessary to stretch legs after jogging if I walk before and after?

Tags: running, training, stretching, jogging, walking

so I'm asking this because I'm out jogging every other day on a hill near my house, but to get to the hill I walk about 30 minutes and I try to walk fast (to go home I walk another 30 minutes), so I was wondering if I really need to stretch my legs considering all the time that I walk before and after jogging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at what stretching accomplishes for you, to see whether your walk home will address it. Some notes from [a Mayo Clinic article](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/fitness/in-depth/stretching/art-20047931):

> Studies about the benefits of stretching have had mixed results. Some
>   show that stretching helps. Other studies show that stretching before
>   or after exercise has little if any benefit and doesn't reduce muscle
>   soreness after exercise. Studies have shown that static stretching
>   performed immediately before a sprint event may decrease performance
>   to a small degree.

And regarding mixed results, [here's a dynamic warm up stretching study that saw pretty good results](http://journals.lww.com/nsca-jscr/Abstract/2008/07000/Four_Week_Dynamic_Stretching_Warm_up_Intervention.36.aspx). This approach was using the now maligned concept of stretching before physical training.

> Wrestlers completing the 4-week DWU [Dynamic Stretching Warmup] intervention had several
>   performance improvements, including increases in quadriceps peak
>   torque (11%), broad jump (4%), underhand medicine ball throw (4%),
>   sit-ups (11%), and push-ups (3%). A decrease in the average time to
>   completion of the 300-yd shuttle (-2%) and the 600-m run (-2.4%) was
>   suggestive of enhanced muscular strength, endurance, agility, and
>   anaerobic capacity in the DWU group. ... The findings suggest that
>   incorporation of this specific 4-week DWU intervention into the daily
>   preseason training regimen of wrestlers produced longer-term or
>   sustained power, strength, muscular endurance, anaerobic capacity, and
>   agility performance enhancements.

So personally, I'd vote to stretch after you get home from your walk/run/walk. You'll be nice and warm, and it will feel great. If you find it boring, incorporate some foam rolling or yoga in as well.

I don't think you *need* to stretch, and I don't think anyone can point to literature that says you absolutely have to. So don't fret it if you can't, but try to work it in.